# Need a single click to load the two pages in the ajax success function

Tags: ajax

Currently, need to click two times on the button ".radioButton" to load the two pages in the ajax success function. How can I change my code to have just one click to load the two pages?

```
$('.select-address').on('click', '.radioButton', function() {
        var form = $('#shippingAddress');
        var action = form.attr('action'),
        method = form.attr('method'),
        data = form.serialize();
        data += '&' + form.find('button[name$=save]:first')[0].name + '=' + form.find('button[name$=save]:first').val();            
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: method,
            data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".mini-billing-address").load(app.urls.miniBillingAddressURL).delay(2000);
                    $(".billing").load(app.urls.paymentMethodURL).delay(2000);
                }
        });             

    });
```